# RDLC how do I redistribute the width of hidden columns / dynamic column width based on visibility

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am currently making a change in an existing RDLC where we wish columns are configurable by the user. Sadly columns being hidden creates a gap. I wish the visible columns fill the empty space / have a dynamic width based on what is available.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution that is natively supported by Reports, nor did I find a solution online that was satisfying. So I wrote some code to manipulate the XML before using it in the reportview. It redistributes the width of hidden columns:

https://github.com/DaveyvanTilburg/RDLCDynamicColumns

Example piece of the xml being altered (can find the full example in github)

The before:

```
<TablixColumn>
    <Width>4.20cm</Width>
</TablixColumn>
<TablixColumn>
    <Width>12.4567cm</Width>
</TablixColumn>
<TablixColumn>
    <Width>10.50cm</Width>
</TablixColumn>
```

The after, where the 2nd column will be hidden, and its width is redistributed over the visible columns:

```
<TablixColumn>
    <Width>10.428350cm</Width>
</TablixColumn>
<TablixColumn>
    <Width>0cm</Width>
</TablixColumn>
<TablixColumn>
    <Width>16.728350cm</Width>
</TablixColumn>
```